# Which SQL Server services do I need for simple home Programming?

Tags: sql-server

I am working on my notebook(4GB ram) with SQL Server 2012 and since I installed with the default settings, It uses too much memory. When I check the processes sqlservr.exe is around 230MB and reportinservicesService.exe around 75 MB, msmdsrv.exe (analysis Services) 35MB etc. 
So my question to those sql experts; If I am just doing simple DB new built, what would you suggest me in order to save some memory? I would like to suspend and run some services on demand only. for example, Can I stop reportingservicesservice.exe. I guess it is only when I need report from sql or is it also for tsql?

thanks for your suggestings.

Comment: We can't answer that, because we don't know exactly what you'll want to use. You can do your own research to see what the options are, evaluate whether or not you'll use each one, and decide what to install or not install. The SQL Server documentation has a pretty substantial discussion on how to proceed through the installation.

Comment: Sorry, I just needed to know If I get any crucial error when I stop all but sqlservr.exe because I need to simply build a new DB and I would probably not need any other operation initially. Once I am ready, If I can simply start others like analysis services, reporting services,Integration services, SQL Agent etc. manually. If someone is not expert and since many people are doing dev on their own pc with restricted resource usage, It might be a helpful question, I thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bare minimum you need to run SQL Server is just sqlservr.exe, i.e. "SQL Server" or "SQL Server (EXPRESS)" in the Services control panel applet. Nothing else is essential.

You don't need any of the below to be running

- Freetext (filter) daemon
- Reporting services
- Analysis services
- Integration services
- SQL Server Agent
- SQL VSS writer

You can go back and enable them when you get to the point where you are working with those features.